# what is the fast way to drop columns in pandas dataframe from a list of column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out the fastest way to drop columns in df using a list of column names. this is a fancy feature reduction technique.
This is what I am using now, and it is taking forever. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

```
    important2=(important[:-(len(important)-500)]) 
    for i in important:
        if i in important2:
            pass
        else:
            df_reduced.drop(i, axis=1, inplace=True)
    df_reduced.head()
```

Comment: Using del df[col] was hundreds of times faster for me than using df.drop(col).

Comment: @David - can you give us the context for that test?  I just tried to replicate it with 100 columns and 100,000 rows and `drop()`, `del()`, and a list (`df = df[my_list]`) were all equally performant.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

use a `list` containing the columns to be dropped:

```
good_bye_list = ['column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3']
df_reduced.drop(good_bye_list, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: This is definitely the "best" way to do it; however, any idea why it would take a long time to run. I have a large dataframe (2 million observations, 98 columns) but still...this should be very fast? Unless I'm missing something. It took me 1min+ to delete two columns.

Comment: why use a list when .drop provides this functionality?

`df_reduced.drop(columns=['column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3'], inplace=True)`

that's more pythonic/readable anyway